# Get the last file name in a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, ls

In a directory, I have the following files:

```
myfile_v01.txt
myfile_v02.txt
myfile_v03.txt
```

How to make a bash script that detects the value of the last version and put the filename of this last version into a variable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not very refined but seems functional:

```
var=$(ls | sort -V | tail -n 1)
```

Then you have the last file stored in `$var`

Comment: fyi: Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1) : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @MarZab Yes, you're right. I've seen that article already and it does have some valid points.

Comment: This does not work this filenames with carry returns !

Answer (score 5):

There are two obvious approaches, you can either parse the file name or look for the latest file:

1. Parse the file name, this assumes all files are named as in your example:

   ```
   $ latest=myfile_v$(
       for f in myfile_v*; do 
         ver=${f##myfile_v}; ver=${ver%.txt}; echo $ver; 
       done | sort -n | tail -n 1).txt
   ```
2. Get the newest file (assuming relatively sane file names that don't contain newlines)

   ```
   $ latest=$(ls -tr | tail -n 1)
   ```

Comment: what does -tr option do ?

Comment: @Ash it sorts by time (`-t`) in reverse order (`-r`) so the last file is the newest

Comment: Far more simple : for f in myfile_v*; do true; done ; echo "$f"

Comment: @Vouze try that with a file named `myfile_v11.txt`. You can't assume the shell will sort numerically, in fact you can assume that it won't which is why `myfile_v11` is sorted before `myfile_v02`. As for simple, this does the same as your command but is considerably shorter and avoids the shell loop entirely: `set -- myfile*; echo "${@: -1}"`. It's just that these approaches don't work because they sort lexically.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution which uses globbing (so does not rely on [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)), like terdon's first solution, but doesn't need to iterate over all files:

```
myfiles=(myfile_v*)
lastfile="${myfiles[${#myfiles[@]}-1]}"
unset myfiles
```

First, all matching files are read into an array. Then, the last element of the array gets assigned to `$lastfile`. Finally, the array isn't needed anymore, so it can be deleted.

Unfortunately, `bash` (at least to my knowledge) doesn't support sorting the result from globbing<sup>#</sup>, so this example works fine with you given naming scheme (exactly two digits, also for versions < 10), but will fail for `myfile_v1.txt`, `myfile_v2.txt`, ..., `myfile_v10.txt`.

---

<sup>#</sup> `zsh` (of course `;)`) does, so `zsh% myfiles=(myfile_v*(n)); lastfile="${myfiles[-1]}"; unset myfiles` wouldn't suffer from this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Use bash build-in facility. There is no external command, pipe, subshell. Thus, there is no fork() involved.

```
set -- /path/to/myfile_v*
latest="${!#}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nice idea. We can also use function : last_arg(){ la=${!#}; } ; last_arg /path/to/myfile_v* ; echo "$la"

Answer (score 0):

I can summarize those good methods :

With "for" (this works with any shell!):

```
for f in myfile_v*
do true
done
echo "$f"
```

Using table :

```
myfiles=(myfile_v*)
lastfile="${myfiles[-1]}"
unset myfiles
echo "$lastfile"
```

With function arguments and global var :

```
function last_arg(){
  la="${!#}"
}
last_arg myfile_v*
echo "$la"
```

Those methods are using only internal commands of shells. "sort", "ls", "tail" are external programs : they have some launching cost.

Answer (score -1):

I used a combination of terdon (see above) approaches:

```
$ latest=$(ls | sort -n | tail -n 1)
```

My setting: all files are in the same folder, and there are no other files there.

Comment: This does not work with filenames with carry returns.

Comment: That may be, but how often do you encounter filenames with CR?